# Compare text in multiple columns and change cell color based results

Tags: excel, colors, vba

I have a spreadsheet with 11,000 entries. I need help with a macro to check the distribution of specific data based on:

- RowCode in column C
- Position form in column H, and
- Quadrant located in column M.

The RowCode always contains a series of numbers and a letter either A or B (01A-01) the numbers associated with A are typically in the lower range like A1 to 22 and the numbers associated with B are typically in the higher range like B23 to 76 but this can vary from time to time.

[image: Screenshot of an example Excel Worksheet]

The quadrant in column M identifies location, this is always either `NW`, `SW`, `NE`, or `SE`. All `NW` or `NE` rows should be in the lower number range of the A section and all `SW` or `SE` rows should be in the higher number range of the B sections as noted below.

- NW: 1-22
- NE: 1-22
- SW: 22-76
- SE: 22-76

The last condition to be met is the “position form” located in column H. This column will contain either `East` or `West` based on the data in column M. If column M has `NE` or `SE` in it column H should reflect `West`. If column H has `NW` or `SW` in it column H should reflect `East`.

I would like a macro to check all these conditions and highlight the cell in the column that does not meet these conditions so I can determine what’s incorrect and make the correction manually.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This can be achieved without any VBA at all, using conditional formatting and the [indirect function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261). For example: `=AND(OR(=INDIRECT("M" & ROW()) = "NW", =INDIRECT("M" & ROW()) = "NE"), =RIGHT(INDIRECT("C" & ROW()), 2) >= "22")`

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, maybe I don’t completely understand how to apply the information you offered or I am doing something but, that’s not exactly working. This seems to be a formula that I would have to enter into another cell, column and preform this task on a row by row basis and unfortunately I don’t have that much freedom on the worksheet.

Comment: I would like to use a macro for this because it allows the freedom of searching the data without having to use or input more data on the worksheet, kind of like the macro included below. It allows me to select a cell and it searches the entire column of the selected cell and simply highlights cells that are duplicates. I am pretty much trying to do the same thing but, in this case search two different columns based on the criteria mentioned previously.  Can this be done?

Comment: Sub FindDups()
       ScreenUpdating = False
   FirstItem = ActiveCell.Value
   SecondItem = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value
   Offsetcount = 1
   Do While ActiveCell <> ""
      If FirstItem = SecondItem Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(Offsetcount, 0).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
       Offsetcount = Offsetcount + 1
       SecondItem = ActiveCell.Offset(Offsetcount, 0).Value
     Else
       ActiveCell.Offset(Offsetcount, 0).Select
       FirstItem = ActiveCell.Value
       SecondItem = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value
       Offsetcount = 1
      End If
   Loop
   ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Comment: Andre, please use the [edit] link to place additional details _directly in your question_ instead of in comments.